# cors problem when working with different ports and fetch

Tags: javascript, php

I work with node on port 3000 and have a php backend on a different port. I use 'fetch' to send and retrieve data from the php backend on the different port.

I need to send cookies with the fetch request to tell php which session should be used. But I always get a cors error.

I got told that the `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the htaccess file cannot be set to '*' (allow all domains), when 'credentials' are set to 'include', so I entered a complete domain (http://localhost:3000). But then I get this error: `Reason: expected ‘true’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Credentials’` and a link that could help me: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowCredentials

there stands, when I use the fetch API, I have to set the credentials to 'omit' instead of 'include' but then the fetch api sends no cookies.

I am completely lost and need help. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Just set the credentials Headers in your htaccess: Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true